# How to enumerate an arbitrary set that conforms to NSFastEnumeration

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsenumerator, objective-c-protocol

I am trying to enumerate over a bunch of objects which, depending on the situation, may be either an NSArray or an NSOrderedSet. Since both conform to NSFastEnumeration, I would expect this to work:

```
id<NSFastEnumeration> enumerableSet =
(test) ?
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", nil] :
[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", nil];

NSEnumerator *e = [enumerableSet objectEnumerator];
```

However, I get the following compiler error:

No known instance method for selector 'objectEnumerator'.

I suspect there is some syntax error here, I haven't worked much with the id construct before. I could convert one or both of the sets to a common class, but if possible I'd like to understand better what's going on here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`objectEnumerator` is not declared in the `NSFastEnumeration` protocol, therefore using `[enumerableSet objectEnumerator];` will not work because you are working with type `id' which doesn't define that method.

Since `objectEnumerator` is declared as a property of a NSArray and a NSSet (with no common super class), you will need to set the enumerator from a variable which knows that it is an array/set.  I.e.:

```
NSEnumerator *e = 
(test) ?
[[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", nil] objectEnumerator]:
[[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", nil] objectEnumerator];
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, never mind. I just found my answer. objectEnumerator is not part of the protocol - so although both NSArray and NSOrderedSet *have* an objectEnumerator message, I can't use it this way. Instead, this seems to work:

```
NSEnumerator *e =
(test) ?
[[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", nil] objectEnumerator]:
[[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", nil] objectEnumerator];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have objects that conform to the `NSFastEnumeration` protocol, but you are trying to use ‘slow’ enumeration with `NSEnumerator`. Instead, use fast enumeration:

```
id<NSFastEnumeration> enumerableSet =
(test) ?
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", nil] :
[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", nil];

for (id object in enumerableSet) {
    // ...
}
```

See [*Fast Enumeration Makes It Easy to Enumerate a Collection*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/FoundationTypesandCollections/FoundationTypesandCollections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH7-SW30) in Apple’s *Programming with Objective-C*.

I recommend using fast enumeration instead of `NSEnumerator` wherever possible; fast enumeration is clearer, more concise and faster.